# Is there a better way to remove items from a list that exists in another?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list with object of type myType and have a second list with objects of the same type. This objects has an ID property and the objects from first list are different of the items of the second list. Also that I know that in both lists, there are not two or more objects with the same ID.

I would like to remove the items from the first list which ID are in the second list and later add the items of the second list to the first list.

I am thinking in this code:

```
    Dictionary<long, int> myDicIdWithPositionFirstList = new Dictionary<long, int>();
    for(int i = 0; i < myFirstList.Count; i++)
    {
        myDicIdWithPositionFirstList.Add(myFirstList[i].ID, i);
    }


    foreach (MyType iterator in mySecondList)
    {
        int myPosition = (myDicIdWithPositionFirstList.ContainsKey(iterator.ID) ? myDicIdWithPositionFirstList[iterator.ID] : -1;
        DgdOrdenesTrabajo.RemoveAt(myPosition);
        MyFirstList.Add(iterator);
    }
```

The idea it is create a diccitionary with the ID and position of the object of the first list. That has a O(n) complexity.

Later, I iterate the second list. I check if there is in the first list. If it is in the first list, I get the position in the dictionary, that is O(1) and I delete from the position I know.

But I don't if really it is a good way to do or there are another better way, simplier and faster in performance.

Thanks.

Comment: i would sort all Id`s and use binary search to locate duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if the lists contain unique objects (unique IDs) then use the collection meant for uniqueness: a *Set*, `HashSet<MyObject>` comes to mind as good choice.

If `MyObject` doesn’t implement value equality based on `ID` then create the sets with the overload that lets you define a custom `IEqualityComparer<MyObject>`.

Once you’ve done that, simply iterate set 2 and check if each object is contained in set 1. If it is, remove from set 1 and add object from set 2 to set 1.

Comment: And if I implement the IEqualityComparer<object> the hashet will be O(1) too?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía Yes, that won't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to get the union of the two lists, then one method is to use Enumerable.Union, which uses the default equality comparer.  Or you could just filter out duplicates in the second set and then add that filtered list to the first list.  E.g.,

```
MasterList.AddRange(SecondList.Where(i => !MasterList.Any(m => m.MyId == i.MyId)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is `O(n)`, where `n` is size of your *MyFirstList* - you deleting element at index, so right part is always shifted, so it is `O(n)`. Even if it is linked list, RemoveAt will take `O(n)` time. Overall your implementation is `O(m*n)` instead of naive `O(m*(n+1))`

Better way is to not use lists at all - use binary tree, with your *ID* as a key. So your structures will be stored in *SortedDictionary* instead of *List* and
*Delete/Update/Create* of single item will take `O(log(n))` and two collection syncrhonization will take `O(m*log(n))`:

```
var myFirstDictionary = new SortedDictionary(myFirstList.Count);
foreach(var item in myFirstList)
{
    myFirstDictionary[item.Id] = item;
}
//updating/creating values in first list by using second list values
foreach(var item in mySecondList)
{
    myFirstDictionary[item.Id] = item;
}
```

**PS**

You actually don't need explicit deletion because you add new element as replacement. So, you can simply update value at specified index, instead of deleting it, and add otherwise:

```
foreach (MyType iterator in mySecondList)
{
    int myPosition = (myDicIdWithPositionFirstList.ContainsKey(iterator.ID) ? myDicIdWithPositionFirstList[iterator.ID] : -1;
    if(myPosition >= 0)
        MyFirstList[i] = iterator;
    else
        MyFirstList.Add(iterator);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below which would list all the items that are not contained in your firstlist

```
var result = DgdOrdenesTrabajo.FindAll(v => !mySecondList.FindAll(var=>myFirstList.Any(var1=>(var1.ID==var.ID)))
                                                         .Any(v2=>v2.ID==v.ID)).ToList<MyType>();
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you simply need a distinct union if i am not mistaken

> I would like to remove the items from the first list which ID are in the second list and later add the items of the second list to the first list.

```
void Main()
{
    var first = new []
    {
        new MyType{Id = 11, Name = "John"},
        new MyType{Id = 12, Name = "Jack"},
        new MyType{Id = 13, Name = "Jim"},
        new MyType{Id = 14, Name = "Joel"},
        new MyType{Id = 15, Name = "Jay"},
    };

    var second = new[]
    {
        new MyType{Id = 21, Name = "Jake"},
        new MyType{Id = 22, Name = "Jan"},
        new MyType{Id = 13, Name = "Jim"},
        new MyType{Id = 14, Name = "Joel"},
        new MyType{Id = 23, Name = "Jane"},
        new MyType{Id = 24, Name = "Jade"},
    };

    var results = first
        .Union(second)
        .Distinct(new MyTypeComparer());
    results.Dump();

    //11 John
    //12 Jack
    //13 Jim
    //14 Joel
    //15 Jay
    //21 Jake
    //22 Jan
    //23 Jane
    //24 Jade
}

public class MyType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyTypeComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyType>
{
    public bool Equals(MyType x, MyType y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyType obj)
    {
        return obj.Id ^ 13;
    }
}
```